# Unable to find element in a form class or div class

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I am unable to find an element in a form class or div class:

```
//Tried this clicking on Source name.
driver.findElement(By.id("__BVID__62")).click();
//Typing into Source name.
driver.findElement(By.id("__BVID__63")).sendKeys(new String[]{"CNN"});
```

I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class='form-control') and type='text']")).sendKeys("CNN");
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="card-body">
<fieldset id="_BVID__62" role="group" aria-labelledby="__BVID__62__BV_label" class="b-form-group form-group">
<legend id="_BVID__62__BV_label" class="col-form-label pt-0">Source Name</legend>
<div role="group" aria-labelledby="_BVID__62__BV_label" class="">
<input id="__BVID__63" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement input = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-body']/descendant::div/input[contains(@id,'BVID')]")));
input.sendKeys("CNN");
```

Comment: tried this but now its asking giving me error by: ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
     ("//div[@class='card-body']/descendant::input[@class='form-control']"));

Comment: by.xpath? should use that element?

Comment: No, actually elementToBeClickable takes webElement

Comment: error message : The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: error message: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
 waiting for presence of element located 
by: By.xpath: //div[@class='card-body']/descendant::input[@class='form-control'] 
(tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'

Comment: I've changed the xpath now ,  please check ! copy the entire code !

Comment: i have check something before this code there is another item that must be clicked this is the HTML code for that item : <li class="px-3 nav-item active"><a aria-disabled="false" href="#/sources" class="nav-link">Sources</a></li>

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sources")).click();

Comment: i have a question, if i have switched to a frame in my code and now in this frame im directed to another HTML url but there is no frame in this html, do i still need to switch frames to this new HTML? As i dont find any frames in this new URL there is just a body class with div class?

Comment: If you have access of that frame and doing some operation on it and then you are navigating to a URL in same frame , you do not need to switch now , but if newly opened URL has opened in a new tab , then you might have to use getWindowsHandles()

Comment: If my answer and support has helped you to resolve your issue , kindly accept it by clicking on check mark just under the down vote button and beside my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the desired element is having a dynamic `ID`. So to send text to the `<input>` node you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and starts-with(@id,'__BVID__') and @type='text']"))).sendKeys("CNN");
```